# Can anyone point me towards tutorials describing how to use the Kalman filter for forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, references, kalman-filter

I am trying to find any guides on how to use Kalman filters with ARIMA models but the only sources I have found have been highly technical that I can't really understand. Can anyone point me towards tutorials or books that might be friendlier to a beginner?

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=CaCcOwJPytQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Kalman filter methodology is a fairly advanced topic in econometrics, hence it is quite difficult to find simple examples, both because it is a complex topic that requires a deeper knowledge of the maths behind it, and because it is easier to make tutorials of simple things.

However, here you can find a quite simple example by Maitra, ["State Space Model and Kalman Filter for Prediction"](https://towardsdatascience.com/state-space-model-and-kalman-filter-for-time-series-prediction-basic-structural-dynamic-linear-2421d7b49fa6) in R on Kalman filter for DLM, that is a generalization of ARIMA with external regressors.

Nevertheless, since you are interested in time series forecasting and estimation, I suggest you to look at the [forecast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf) package in R by Professor Rob J. Hyndman (there should also be a Python version), that allows to estimate various time series models in state-space forms, and maybe the book ["Forecasting: Principles and Practice"](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) by Rob J. Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos.

Comment: Including a full title in case the link goes dead is an encouraged practice.

Answer (score 1):

The best I found till now is this open source interactive book: [Kalman and Bayesian Filters in Python](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python)

Hope this helps !